# mongo DB get object and partial array in object using java

Tags: arrays, mongodb

my mongo object will be like this

```js
{
    "colID" : "1",
    "title" : "title",
    "desciption : "description",
    "array" : [
        { "identifier" : "1", "title" : "test1"},
        { "identifier" : "2", "title" : "test2"},
    ]
}
```

Input is : colID is 1 and identifier is 2. Now I would like to get the following response

```js
{
    "colID" : "1",
    "title" : "title",
    "desciption : "description",
    "array" : [
        { "identifier" : "2", "title" : "test2"}
    ]
}
```

Please help I am very new to mongoDB. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $elemMatch operator.

Look the MongoDB documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: note that you will just get the first match of that array.